# I'm Looking For Free Graphic Design Software Like Adobe Photoshop

Tags: free

I love the idea of using Photoshop, though it's well out of my price range. I'm looking for free software that is very much the same feeling of Photoshop but for free and for use on a Windows 10 PC (ASUS X453M Series Notebook).

If it helps, I have experience in Photoshop but the last time I used it was last year when my old hard drive broke and I can't no longer access it nor find where I put the original Photoshop Elements 2.0 CD. I've also used Photoshop 5.0 in late 2004 with some of my early artwork and graphic designs being created on Photoshop 5.0 by my hands.

Anyways, I'm looking for a really good answer (free software only), so that it helps others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) (GNU Image Manipulation Program) would be the best alternative to Photoshop that is free.

> GIMP is a cross-platform image editor available for GNU/Linux, OS X,
>   Windows and more operating systems.

from GIMP.org

There are a lot of similarities and functions between GIMP and Photoshop. It won't have everything that the latest Photoshop version has but it is a very good alternative.